# Python + Django / I want to use "http Post " to register email and password. HTTP/1.0 400

Tags: python, django, post, httpie

Python + Django / I want to use "http Post " to register email and password. 
But I got this message  HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUESTAllow: POST, OPTIONS
 "Password is required."

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please show us the code you are using for this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put a token CRSF (Cross Site Request Forgery) in the template? Like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect    
from django.shortcuts import render

def view(request):
      return render_to_response('login.html',RequestContext(request,{}))
```

in a template like this:

```
{% block content %}      
  <form action='/register/' method='post' >{% csrf_token %}

  </form>  
{% endblock %}
```

Django doc Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/csrf/